# Operating on every element of a list without for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

Now I know this question is as bizarre as it sounds, but I have found myself in a situation where I may need to avoid looping over the list, unless I manage to identify the source of the problem.

The problem:

```
def SomeFunction(args):
    someList = [here, are, list, elements]
    print (someList) # works normal
    for elem in someList:
        print (elem) # side effects observed here (and not sure why at this stage), only the first element is printed
```

Is there any other way of accessing list elements in a manner that a for loop would do?

Comment: Beep, beep! Back the truck up. This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) if I've ever seen one. Why are you avoiding a `for` loop? Let us help you identify the root problem so you don't have to add a kludgy workaround.

Comment: I see!! Sure, let me first try some other workarounds and see if I may spot the bug.

Comment: Writing a [mcve] so we can see those `# side effects` in real life should really help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion or slicing.

```
def print_ele(elements):
    if(len(elements)>0):
        print(elements[0])
        print_ele(elements[1:])

//Or 
elements[0:2]
```

Comment: This is an O(n^2) way of iterating over a list.

Answer (score 0):

In general, this can be achieved using recursion.

Here is the algorithm that I used to process lists using recursion :-

Function process_list(takes the first element of a list as an argument)

1. If the list has ended:
    return(end function execution).
2. Process the current element.
3. Call the function process_list(pass it the next element in the list).

Comment: How does your function find the next element in the list, when the input is only the first element in the list (not the whole list)? Python's lists are not linked lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the list using while loop:

```
i = 0
sizeofList = len(wordList) 
while i < sizeofList :
    print(wordList[i]) 
    i += 1
```